# Uniforms management

Tags: glsl

I wanted to know if there is any special optimization going on with uniforms and shaders.
The issue I'm facing is that when increasing an uniform which is clamped to an option by a modulo, it only works with odd numbers. As if the uniform was set twice and skipped a frame.
if uniform management strictly implementation dependent or does opengl try to cache it ?
I'm asking this question since I'm working on a program that I did not code myself for implementing clipmaps voxelization. And the only way I don't get alternating voxelization (clearly visible level 0, 1 ... being voxelized one after the other) is by modifying the index in the function that sets the uniform for the shaders.

Comment: Can you show us the code for a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, and images of the output you're getting, explaining how they differ from what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there's way too much code. I'm just sure that the function that sets the uniform is called only once but since that per object it increases the level too much.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that each meshes sets uniforms, and since I increase the level in the function that sets the uniforms, the lod increases by the number of object for each frame.
And even worst, uniforms are set for each vertex...

Comment: That's the kind of thing that should be stated in your question in order to get accurate help, which is why we ask to see minimal code samples. Now that you've isolated the cause of the problem, do you want to edit your question to ask for a different solution for managing voxelization levels that will handle multiple objects correctly?

Comment: @DMGregory, no i'll just leave it as is, I've solved the issue in between and the clipmaps are fine, it's for armory3d in case you'r interested.